# JHipster Blueprint - Generate files with a specific path using templates | Get default java package name

Tags: javascript, jhipster

EDIT : the former question was "JHipster Blueprint - How to get default Java package name ?"

I am developing a blueprint with JHipster that overrides the entity-server sub-generator. The desired behaviour is to replace all files in /src/main/java/defaultpackageName/domain/ from the project generated by the blueprint with my generated files. This is my code (files.js):

```
const entityServerFiles = {
    noHibernate: [
        //domain files
        {
            path: 'src/main/java/XXX/domain/',
            templates: [
                {
                    file: 'Entity.java',
                    renameTo: generator => `${generator.persistClass}.java`
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};

function writeFiles() {
    return {
        write() {
            this.writeFilesToDisk(entityServerFiles, this, false);
        }
    }
}

module.exports = {
    writeFiles
};
```

For now it just creates a folder XXX in /src/main/java/ with my generated files in it.

**What would I need to write in the XXX in path: 'src/main/java/XXX/domain/' in order to generate the files at the right place?**

I did some digging on github on the generator-jhipster project and the prompt asking the user for the default java package name is in /generator-jhipster/generators/java/index.cjs/. This is the whole code https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/blob/main/generators/java/index.cjs
But I just took the important part:

```
const {
  PACKAGE_NAME,
  PACKAGE_NAME_DEFAULT_VALUE,
  PRETTIER_JAVA_INDENT,
  PRETTIER_JAVA_INDENT_DEFAULT_VALUE,
  BUILD_TOOL,
  BUILD_TOOL_DEFAULT_VALUE,
  BUILD_TOOL_PROMPT_CHOICES,
} = require('./constants.cjs');

get prompting() {
    return {
      async showPrompts() {
        if (this.shouldSkipPrompts()) return;
        await this.prompt(
          [
            {
              name: PACKAGE_NAME,
              type: 'input',
              validate: input => this.validatePackageName(input),
              message: 'What is your default Java package name?',
              default: () => this.sharedData.getConfigDefaultValue(PACKAGE_NAME, PACKAGE_NAME_DEFAULT_VALUE),
            },
          ],
          this.config
        );
      },
    };
  }
```

From what I understand, I just need to access the PACKAGE_NAME constant from my blueprint and it should work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the solution...

```
const entityServerFiles = {
    noHibernate: [
        //domain files
        {
            path: 'src/main/java/',
            templates: [
                {
                    file: 'package/domain/Entity.java',
                    renameTo: generator => `${generator.entityAbsoluteFolder}/domain/${generator.persistClass}.java`
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};

function writeFiles() {
    return {
        write() {
            this.writeFilesToDisk(entityServerFiles, this, false);
        }
    }
}

module.exports = {
    writeFiles
};
```

The path property specifies the path inside the templates folder. Meanwhile, you can specify the path you want your files to be generated inside the project in the renameTo property.

So the answer to my question is ${generator.entityAbsoluteFolder} which had nothing to do with my original hypothesis, but this question can also be useful for writing templates in general.